# Can State Pattern help with read only states?

Tags: state-pattern, design-patterns, c#

I'm trying to model a certain process and I'm thinking that the State Pattern might be a good match.  I'd like to get your feedback though about whether State will suit my needs and how it should be combined with my persistence mechanism.

I have a CMS that has numerous objects, for example, Pages.  These objects (we'll use the example of Pages, but it's true of most objects) can be in one of a number of states, 3 examples are:
Unpublished
Published
Reworking

When Unpublished, they are editable.  Once Published, they are not editable, but can be moved into the Reworking state.  In the Reworking state they are editable again and can be Republished.

Obviously the decision for whether these Pages are editable should be in the models themselves and not the UI.  So, the State pattern popped into mind.  However, how can I prevent assigning values to the object's properties?  It seems like a bad idea to have a check on each property setter:

```
if (!CurrentState.ReadOnly)
```

Any ideas how to work this?  Is there a better pattern for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

I actually thought of a method this morning that would work with your specific case and be a lot easier to maintain.  I'll leave the original two points here, but I'm going to recommend the final option instead, so skip to the "better method" section.

1. Create a `ThrowIfReadOnly` method, which does what it says on the tin.  This is slightly less repetitive and avoids the nesting.
2. Use an interface.  Have an `IPage` that implements the functionality you want, have every public method return an `IPage`, then have two implementations, an `EditablePage` and a `ReadOnlyPage`.  The `ReadOnlyPage` just throws an exception whenever someone tries to modify it.  Also put an `IsReadOnly` property (or `State` property) on the `IPage` interface so consumers can actually check the status without having to catch an exception.

Option (2) is more or less how `IList` and `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` work together.  It saves you the trouble of having to do a check at the beginning of every method (thus eliminating the risk of forgetting to validate), but requires you to maintain two classes.

**-- Better Method --**

A proper technical spec would help a lot to clarify this problem.  What we really have here is:

- A *series* of arbitrary "write" actions;
- Each action has the *same* outcome, dependent on the state:
- Either the action is taken (unpublished/reworking), or fails/no-ops (read-only).

What really needs to be abstracted is not so much the *action itself*, but the *execution* of said action.  Therefore, a little bit of functional goodness will help us here:

```
public enum PublishingState
{
    Unpublished,
    Published,
    Reworking
}

public delegate void Action();

public class PublishingStateMachine
{
    public PublishingState State { get; set; }

    public PublishingStateMachine(PublishingState initialState)
    {
        State = initialState;
    }

    public void Write(Action action)
    {
        switch (State)
        {
            case PublishingState.Unpublished:
            case PublishingState.Reworking:
                action();
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The operation is invalid " +
                    "because the object is in a read-only state.");
        }
    }
}
```

Now it becomes almost trivial to write the classes themselves:

```
public class Page
{
    private PublishingStateMachine sm = new
        PublishingStateMachine(PublishingState.Unpublished);

    private string title;
    private string category;

    // Snip other methods/properties
    // ...

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { sm.Write(() => title = value; }
    }

    public string Category
    {
        get { return category; }
        set { sm.Write(() => category = value; }
    }

    public PublishingState State
    {
        get { return sm.State; }
        set { sm.State = value; }
    }
}
```

Not only does this more-or-less implement the State pattern, but you don't need to maintain separate classes or even separate code paths for the different states.  If you want to, for example, turn the `InvalidOperationException` into a no-op, just remove the `throw` statement from the `Write` method.  Or, if you want to add an additional state, like `Reviewing` or something like that, you just need to add one `case` line.

This won't handle state transitions for you or any really complex actions that do different things depending on the state (other than just "succeed" or "fail"), but it doesn't sound like you need that.  So this gives you a drop-in state implementation that requires almost no extra code to use.

Of course, there's still the option of dependency injection/AOP, but there's obviously a lot of overhead associated with that approach, and I probably wouldn't use it for something so simple.

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for.  I really like the syntax, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using wikipedia's [Java example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern#Java), the structure has a Context, which calls methods defined in the base State, which the concrete states override.

[image: State Diagram]

In your case, the context is something like a page.  In some states, the `edit()` method is simply a no-op.  Some of the actions on the context may execute a state change implicitly.   There is never any need in the client code to test which state you are in.

Comment: Yes, but Pages have one set of properties and other objects, say Modules, have others.  How would you deal with that?

Comment: I think the state pattern is a great idea for handling workflow states.  That was pretty much the scope of the question.  I think design problems beyond that scope deserve their own questions.  In particular, "modules" is one of those utility words that requires a definition.

Comment: +1 for *There is never any need in the client code to test which state you are in.* I.E. if there is, the pattern is not implemented correctly.